# How to implement weighted-softmax in chainer

Tags: softmax, chainer

I am re-produce a paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.11575 : where it has one formula:
[image]

But I searched chainer, it only has F.softmax,but it cannot add weight on to it.
How to reimplement that formula?

Comment: You want to add the term "w_G^{mn}"? 
How about "adding a value log(w_G^{mn})" to each output before applying usual softmax?

Comment: You are genius! yes, maths laws allows to do that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add the term `w_G^{mn}`, I guess "adding a value log(w_G^{mn})" to each output before applying usual softmax should have a same effect.